# how to fetch the data of column from txt file without column name in unix?

Tags: awk

This  is `student.txt` file:

```
RollNo|Name|Marks
123|Raghu|80
342|Maya|45
561|Gita|56
480|Mohan|71
```

---

I want to fetch data from "Marks" column and I used awk command

```
awk -F "|" '{print $3}' student.txt
```

and it gives the output like

```
Marks
80
45
56
71
```

This output included column name that is "Marks" but I only want to fetch the data and show the output like

```
80
45
56
71
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a condition to your `awk` script to print the third field if the input record number is greater 1:

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR>1{print $3}' student.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, this has NOT hard coded field number for `Marks` keyword,in headers it will look for that string and will print only those columns which are under Marks, so even your Marks column is in any field number this should work fine. Written and test in https://ideone.com/Ufq5E2 link.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS="|" }
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i=="Marks"){ field=i }
  }
  next
}
{
  print $field
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

*to fetch data from "Marks" column - -use[ing] awk*:

```
$ awk -F\| '
FNR==1 {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if($i=="Marks")
            next
    exit
}
{
    print $i
}' file
80
45
56
71
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR != 1 {print $3}' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

a non-awk alternative

```
$ sed 1d file | cut -d\| -f3

80
45
56
71
```